# In 2013, I need to use nose1 or nose2 ? What is the future of nose?

Tags: python, testing, nose

I'm wondering what nose version I need to use in 2013 ?
I'm wondering what is the future of nose : nose1 or nose2 ?

I see more activity on nose1 github than nose2 github repository.

Since some months, I try to always use nose2, but I see that I'm alone, everyone
use nose1 around me.

What are your comment about nose2 ?

Best regards,
Stéphane

Comment: Maybe this lik is useful: https://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/differences.html

Comment: This the nose2 author answer : http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.testing.general/5424/focus=5425